# Default OkHttp version shipped with Retrofit2.1?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Could anyone tell me what is the default OkHttp version that comes with Retrofit2.1. Or which one I should use?
My reference : https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-upgrade-guide-from-1-9
This link is not exactly clear whether I should or should not use OkHttp 3.3.1.

Answer (score 4):

You can find dependencies versions on [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com)
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.1.0

> com.squareup.okhttp3 » okhttp 3.3.0

You can use 3.3.1 version for now, just add dependency in your gradle file and set `OkHttpClient` to `Retrofit` instance.

Comment: how can we mention to retrofit 2 to not use in-built okhttp version but different one?